# @Inject in a Java EE application client does not work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, separation-of-concerns, application-client

#### Problem

Injecting an enterprise java bean with `@EJB` in an application client, launched with Java web start and from a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) server.. works as long as the requirements are fulfilled [*see note at bottom*]. But all fails if I inject something using `@Inject`, despite whatever resource type we're trying to inject. And I know it failed because I shall get a `NullPointerException` if I try to use the injected resource. That tells me the annotation processor has completely forgot `@Inject`.

Not only am I intrigued that `@EJB` work flawlessly at the same time `@Inject` does not work at all, I also reason that this "silent failure" of the injection must be a violation of the [Java EE 6 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316). The specification says on page 69:

> If the container fails to find a resource needed for injection,
>   initialization of the class must fail, and the class must not be put
>   into service.

This issue *could* be related to, or an expression of, a [bugg in GlassFish](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11257).

#### My end goal..

.. is to separate API from implementation so that I get a much easier job trying out different implementations when it's time for performance testing and profiling my application. However I take it this design pattern is pretty much impossible to recreate in an application client then? My immediate approach is to create new instances of all the implementations in the `Main` class or use factories. Of course the best solution of all would be to use qualifiers!

**Note**: Requirements for injection in application clients are that CDI must be enabled for the component (package must contain the file *beans.xml*, most likely empty if you're used to annotations!) and **support** of CDI in application clients is actually optional, implementation specific. Moreover, if CDI is enabled and supported, then you should know that the application client container can only be active during the boot of the client and requires thus that the resources be injected into the `Main` class and that the fields are `static`.

Comment: You're trying to get a reference to a remote EJB?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get a specific implementation of an interface.

Comment: As far as I am aware, app client is really only applicable around remotable objects.  CDI has no remoting capabilities.  I doubt it something any of them are particularly thinking of since it's much easier to simply run CDI in your client than it is to try to use the app server to do this work.  Looking at this thread https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/lists/jsr342-experts/archive/2012-12/message/40 it appears that basic support was added in CDI 1.1/JEE 7.

Comment: did your other question about appclient answer this?